# Is there a setting change we need to make for iBatis to MyBatis conversion tool?

Tags: mybatis, ibatis

Has anyone used the iBatis to MyBatis conversion tool like in https://code.google.com/p/mybatis/wiki/DocUpgrade3? Did you need to make a setting change for the tool to work? 
I've tried 2-3 versions of this tool, but I keep getting this error:

```
     [xslt] Loading stylesheet C:\<some-path>\migrate.xslt
     [xslt] : Error! Connection timed out: connect
     [xslt] : Error! com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeExcepti
on: Connection timed out: connect
     [xslt] Failed to process null

BUILD FAILED
C:\<some-path>\build.xml:2
4: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerExce
ption: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Connection
 timed out: connect
```

Also, the way I tried to run it is as follows:
In a command prompt, I changed to the directory where the zip file was extracted. Then I put in one of the SQL map files into the Source folder. Then I went back to the command prompt, and ran the command "ant". I tried this command with 2-3 options too, but none of them worked. All of them gave the same error. It seems like some kind of a proxy setting kind of issue, from what I've found so far. But I don't exactly know what the error is and what the solution is, beyond this. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Does anyone have any idea about this? I could really do with some help with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this:

1. At first, I tried to run the Ant task by setting this property via the command prompt:
   set ANT_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080"

And then ran in the same session: ant

But this continued to give me the same error.

2. So, I took out the `<!DOCTYPE..>` line from the source file, and then did the above steps. It worked like magic!